# IBM Watson IoT Platform: What is the best way to send heartbeat from IP capable device to IBM Watson IoT Platform for device tracking

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-watson, watson-iot

I know we can send heartbeat payload through device monitoring topic. But do we have any another way where any IP capable device can send heartbeat to IBM Watson Platform through any IBM services or database for device tracking?

Comment: Can you provide more details about you're trying to achieve?  The IoT platform has the Last Event Cache REST API, which enables you to obtain the last published event, including timestamp.   Or do you need something more directly related to MQTT device monitoring topic?

Answer (score 0):

I assume with "any IP capable device" you mean you don't want/can install a MQTT stack?

You can use HTTP(S) instead, as described [here](http://%20https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/publish-device-events-to-ibm-iot-foundation-using-https/)

fyi: You don't need the IBM API client, any MQTT library is sufficient then you can also use MQTT instead HTTP(S)